# Unique random string with alphanumberic required in Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I'm using the following code to generate a unique 10-character random string of `[A-Z a-z 0-9]` in Ruby:

```
random_code = [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9'),*('A'..'Z')].shuffle[0, 10].join
```

However, sometimes this random string does not contain a number or an uppercase character. Could you help me have a method that generates a unique random string that requires at least one number, one uppercase and one downcase character?

Comment: Since you want it to be random with side conditions you have to be a little careful.  I would randomly select 1 lowercase letter, 1 uppercase letter and 1 digit, then select 7 more randomly and then shuffle everything.

Comment: There's no rush selecting an answer. Give it *at least* a couple of hours. You don't want to discourage other, possibly better, or just interesting, answers, and a quick selection is not appreciated by those still preparing answers. You just selected my answer. Please consider removing the checkmark for now anyway.

Comment: thanks for reminding me. i have removed it

Comment: @NguyenTuan your code returns 10 unique characters (i.e. no duplicates), is that a requirement?

Comment: yes, it's a requirement

Comment: @NguyenTuan you should update your question accordingly

Comment: thanks, i have updated it.

Comment: "Unique random string" is meaningless. Do you mean (in answer to @Stefan's question) each character in the string only appears once in the string?

Comment: well, I don't mean that. I mean strings created from this method must be different from each other.

Comment: I want to generate tokens from this method. So they must be unique.

Comment: Your example returns 10 unique *characters*, i.e. the characters in the string don't appear twice. It's like drawing 10 items from an urn that contains all 62 items (a-z, A-Z, 0-9), without placing them back in the urn. This might or might not be what you actually want. There is however no guarantee that you don't draw the same 10 items again later. It's just not very likely.

Comment: @NguyenTuan, this is a very interesting algorithmic problem. I updated my answer with analysis and a semi-solution.

Comment: @ndn: Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
down   = ('a'..'z').to_a
up     = ('A'..'Z').to_a
digits = ('0'..'9').to_a
all    = down + up + digits
[down.sample, up.sample, digits.sample].
  concat(7.times.map { all.sample }).
  shuffle.
  join
  #=> "TioS8TYw0F"
```

**[Edit:** The above reflects a misunderstanding of the question. I'll leave it, however. To have no characters appear more than once:

```
def rnd_str
  down   = ('a'..'z').to_a
  up     = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  digits = ('0'..'9').to_a
  [extract1(down), extract1(up), extract1(digits)].
    concat(((down+up+digits).sample(7))).shuffle.join
end

def extract1(arr)
  i = arr.size.times.to_a.sample
  c = arr[i]
  arr.delete_at(i)
  c
end

rnd_str #=> "YTLe0WGoa1" 
rnd_str #=> "NrBmAnE9bT"
```

`down.sample.shift` (etc.) would have been more compact than `extract1`, but the inefficiency was just too much to bear.

If you do not want to repeat random strings, simply keep a list of the ones you generate. If you generate another that is in the list, discard it and generate another. It's pretty unlikely you'll have to generate any extra ones, however. If, for example, you generate 100 random strings (satisfying the requirement of at least one lowercase letter, uppercase letter and digit), the chances that there will be one or more duplicate strings is about one in 700,000:

```
t = 107_518_933_731
n = t+1
t = t.to_f
(1.0 - 100.times.reduce(1.0) { |prod,_| prod * (n -= 1)/t }).round(10)
  #=> 1.39e-07
```

where `t = C(62,10)` and `C(62,10)` is defined below.

**An alternative**

There is a really simple way to do this that turns out to be pretty efficient: just sample without replacement until a sample is found that meets the requirement of at least lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and one digit. We can do that as follows:

```
DOWN   = ('a'..'z').to_a
UP     = ('A'..'Z').to_a
DIGITS = ('0'..'9').to_a
ALL    = DOWN + UP + DIGITS

def rnd_str
  loop do
    arr = ALL.sample(10)
    break arr.shuffle.join unless (DOWN&&arr).empty? || (UP&&arr).empty? || 
    (DIGITS&&arr).empty?
  end
end

rnd_str #=> "3jRkHcP7Ge" 
rnd_str #=> "B0s81x4Jto
```

How many samples must we reject, on average, before finding a "good" one? It turns out (see below if you are *really, really* interested) that the probability of getting a "bad" string (i.e, selecting 10 characters at random from the 62 elements of `all`, without replacement, that has no lowercase letters, no uppercase letters or no digits, is only about 0.15. (15%). That means that 85% of the time no bad samples will be rejected before a good one is found.

It turns out that the expected number of bad strings that will be sampled, before a good string is sampled, is:

```
0.15/0.85 =~ 0.17
```

The following shows how the above probability was derived, should anyone be interested.

Let `n_down` be the number of ways a sample of 10 can be drawn that has no lowercase letters:

```
n_down = C(36,10) = 36!/(10!*(36-10)!)
```

where (the binomial coefficient) `C(36,10)` equals the number of combinations of 36 "things" that can be "taken" 10 at a time, and equals:

```
C(36,10) = 36!/(10!*(36-10)!) #=> 254_186_856
```

Similarly,

```
n_up = n_down #=> 254_186_856
```

and

```
n_digits = C(52,10) #=> 15_820_024_220
```

We can add these three numbers together to obtain:

```
n_down + n_up + n_digits #=> 16_328_397_932
```

This is almost, but not quite, the number of ways to draw 10 characters, without replacement, that contains no lowercase letters characters, uppercase letters or digits. "Not quite" because there is a bit of double-counting going on. The necessary adjustment is as follows:

```
n_down + n_up + n_digits - 2*C(26,10) - 3
  #=> 16_317_774_459
```

To obtain the probability of drawing a sample of 10 from a population of 62, without replacement, that has no lowercase letter, no uppercase letter or no digit, we divide this number by the total number of ways 10 characters can be drawn from 62 without replacement:

```
(16_317_774_459.0/c(62,10)).round(2)
  #=> 0.15
```

Comment: Wouldn't this miss a lot of cases though? Each time you do this you remove one of each set. You will run out of options after `[down, up, digits].map(&:size).min` tries.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I fixed it, and in doing so, got a little carried away.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. But my question is much simpler, I just need a 10-character random string that requires at least 1 number, 1 uppercase and 1 downcase character. And your first anwer solves my problem.

Comment: That's true, but you can use either method, as both produce what you need and efficiency is about the same.

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer. The first and the third versions don't generate unique strings. The second one will fail if you try to generate more than 10 strings. It is the uniqueness part that makes the problem interesting from algorithmic point of view.

Comment: @ndn, I explained in "Edit:" that the first solution reflected my misunderstanding of the question. (I wrote that before the OP clarified with an edit.). I don't understand your objection to #2. Regarding #3, I fixed an error seconds before you submitted your comment. Please have another look at it.

Comment: You have a typo - `are` should be `arr`. But still - this doesn't in any way guarantee uniqueness of all generated strings. About my objection to the second solution - try to run `11.times { [extract1(down), extract1(up), extract1(digits)].concat(((down+up+digits).sample(7))).shuffle.join }`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "uniqueness of all generated strings". As I understand, we are generated just one random 10-character string. No character in the string will be repeated with #2 or #3 (`sample(10)`, for example, will return an array of 10 unique characters.). Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Read the comments below the question. There the OP says that by "unique 10-character random string" he doesn't mean a string where there are no repeating characters but "strings created from this method must be different from each other".

Comment: @ndn, Egad! I hadn't seen some of the more recent comments. I'm now thoroughly confused, as the question and comments are contradictory. It's really late here in Victoria (Canada), so for me it will have to wait until morning. Maybe the dust will have settled by then.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, right, OP didn't use the best wording possible. What he actually wants is pretty much a generator for `[*('a'..'z'), *('0'..'9'), *('A'..'Z')].repeated_combination(10).to_a.shuffle` (minus the cases that don't have a digit and lower/upper case letters).

Comment: @ndn, I did an edit that I trust will address your concerns. As to the method failing if more than 10 random strings are generated, I thought readers would assume the code would be incorporated in method, as I've now shown.

Comment: Not really. Again - none of your solutions satisfy the uniqueness constraint which is the hard part of the problem. The only thing you have said in terms of addressing it was that you can keep the already generated tokens in a set and make checks against this set for each newly generated token. This might work if this was a script that you would run to generate 5, 10, 100 or 1000 tokens. But is completely detrimental if your long running application depends on it. Not only will you need the same amount of memory as generating all permutations right away at some point, but as the number of

Comment: generated tokens approaches the number of possible tokens, the number of retries needed to generate a new token diverges to infinity. A solution is needed that doesn't require you to keep all the tokens, no matter if you generate them all at the beginning or if you add them one by one slowly. You just don't have that much memory.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a script to generate just some small amount of tokens (like *2, 5, 10, 100, 1000, 10 000*, etc), then the best way would be to simply keep the already generated tokens in memory and retry until a new one is generated (statistically speaking, this wont take long). If this is not the case - keep reading.

---

After thinking about it, this problem turned out to be in fact very interenting. For brievety, I will not mention the requirement to have at least one number, capital and lower case letters, but it will be included in the final solution. Also let `all = [*'1'..'9', *'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z']`.

To sum it up, we want to generate k-permutations of n elements with repetition **randomly** with **uniqueness constraint**.
k = 10, n = 61 (`all.size`)

Ruby just so happens to have such method, it's `Array#repeated_permutation`. So everything is great, we can just use:

```
all.repeated_permutation(10).to_a.map(&join).shuffle
```

and pop the resulting strings one by one, right? Wrong! The problem is that the amount of possibilities happens to be:

[k^n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) = 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (`10**61`).

Even if you had an infinetelly fast processor, you still can't hold such amount of data, no matter if this was the count of complex objects or simple bits.

The opposite would be to generate random permutations, keep the already generated in a set and make checks for inclusion before returning the next element. This is just delaying the innevitable - not only you would still have to hold the same amount of information at some point, but as the number of generated permutations grows, the number of tries required to generate a new permutation diverges to infinity.

As you might have thought, the root of the problem is that *randomness* and *uniqueness* hardly go hand to hand.

---

Firstly, we would have to define what we would consider as random. Judging by [the amount](https://xkcd.com/221/) of [nerdy comics](http://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=Random+Nine) on [the subject](http://xkcd.com/1277/), you could deduce that this isn't that black and white either.

An intuitive definition for a random program would be one that doesn't generate the tokens in the same order with each execution. Great, so now we can just take the first n permutations (where `n = rand(100)`), put them at the end and enumerate everything in order? You can sense where this is going. In order for a random generation to be considered good, the generated outputs of consecutive runs should be [equaly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). In simpler terms, the probability of getting any possible output should be equal to **1 / #__all_possible_outputs__**.

---

Now lets explore the boundaries of our problem a little:

The number of possible k-permutations of n elements without repetition is:

[n!/(n-k)!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) = 327_234_915_316_108_800 (`(61 - 10 + 1).upto(61).reduce(:*)`)

Still out of reach. Same goes for

The number of possible full permutations of n elements without repetition:

[n!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation) = 507_580_213_877_224_798_800_856_812_176_625_227_226_004_528_988_036_003_099_405_939_480_985_600_000_000_000_000 (`1.upto(61).reduce(:*)`)

The number of possible k-combinations of n elements without repetition:

[n!/k!(n-k)!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) = 90_177_170_226 (`(61 - 10 + 1).upto(61).reduce(:*)/1.upto(10).reduce(:*)`)

Finally, where we might have a break through with full permutation of k elements without repetition:

[k!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation) = 3_628_800 (`1.upto(10).reduce(:*)`)

**~3.5m** isn't nothing, but at least it's reasonably computable. On my personal laptop `k_permutations = 0.upto(9).to_a.permutation.to_a` took **2.008337** seconds on average. Generally, as computing time goes, this is a lot. However, assuming that you will be running this on an actual server and only once per application startup, this is nothing. In fact, it would even be reasonable to create some seeds. A single `k_permutations.shuffle` took **0.154134** seconds, therefore in about a minute we can acquire *61* random permutations: `k_seeds = 61.times.map { k_permutations.shuffle }.to_a`.

---

Now lets try to convert the problem of k-permutations of n elements without repetition to solving multiple times full k-permutations without repetitions.

A cool trick for generating permutations is using numbers and [bitmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap). The idea is to generate all numbers from *0* to *2^61 - 1* and look at the bits. If there is a `1` on position `i`, we will use the `all[i]` element, otherwise we will skip it. We still didn't escape the issue as *2^61* = 2305843009213693952 (`2**61`) which we can't keep in memory.

Fortunatelly, [another cool trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_power#Algebraic_properties) comes to the rescue, this time from number theory.

> Any *m* consecutive numbers raised to the power of a prime number by modulo of *m* give the numbers from 0 to *m* - 1

In other words:

```
5.upto(65).map { |number| number**17 % 61 }.sort # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
5.upto(65).map { |number| number**17 % 61 } # => [36, 31, 51, 28, 20, 59, 11, 22, 47, 48, 42, 12, 54, 26, 5, 34, 29, 57, 24, 53, 15, 55, 3, 38, 21, 18, 43, 40, 23, 58, 6, 46, 8, 37, 4, 32, 27, 56, 35, 7, 49, 19, 13, 14, 39, 50, 2, 41, 33, 10, 30, 25, 16, 9, 17, 60, 0, 1, 44, 52, 45]
```

Now actually, how random is that? As it turns out - the more common divisors shared by *m* and the selected *m* numbers, the less evenly distributed the sequence is. But we are at luck here - *61^2 - 1* is a prime number (also called [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime)). Therefore, the only divisors it can share are *1* and *61^2 - 1*. This means that no matter what power we choose, the positions of the numbers *0* and *1* will be fixed. That is not perfect, but the other *61^2 - 3* numbers can be found at any position. And guess what - we don't care about *0* and *1* anyway, because they don't have *10* `1`s in their binary representation!

Unfortunatelly, a bottleneck for our randomness is the fact that the bigger prime number we want to generate, the harder it gets. This is the best I can come up with when it comes to generating all the numbers in a range in a shuffled order, without keeping them in memory simultaneously.

---

So to put everything in use:

1. We generate seeds of full permutations of *10* elements.
2. We generate a random prime number.
3. We randomly choose if we want to generate permutations for the next number in the sequence or a number that we already started (up to a finite number of started numbers).
4. We use bitmaps of the generated numbers to get said permutations.

**Note** that this will solve only the problem of k-permutations of n elements without repetition. I still haven't thought of a way to add repetition.

---

**DISCLAIMER: The following code comes with no guarantees of any kind, explicit or implied. Its point is to further express the author's ideas, rather than be a production ready solution**:

```
require 'prime'

class TokenGenerator
  NUMBERS_UPPER_BOUND = 2**61 - 1
  HAS_NUMBER_MASK     = ('1' * 9 + '0' * (61 - 9)).reverse.to_i(2)
  HAS_LOWER_CASE_MASK = ('0' * 9 + '1' * 26 + '0' * 26).reverse.to_i(2)
  HAS_UPPER_CASE_MASK = ('0' * (9 + 26) + '1' * 26).reverse.to_i(2)
  ALL_CHARACTERS = [*'1'..'9', *'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z']
  K_PERMUTATIONS = 0.upto(9).to_a.permutation.to_a # give it a couple of seconds

  def initialize
    random_prime = Prime.take(10_000).drop(100).sample

    @all_numbers_generator = 1.upto(NUMBERS_UPPER_BOUND).lazy.map do |number|
      number**random_prime % NUMBERS_UPPER_BOUND
    end.select do |number|
      !(number & HAS_NUMBER_MASK).zero? and
      !(number & HAS_LOWER_CASE_MASK).zero? and
      !(number & HAS_UPPER_CASE_MASK).zero? and
      number.to_s(2).chars.count('1') == 10
    end

    @k_permutation_seeds  = 61.times.map { K_PERMUTATIONS.shuffle }.to_a # this will take a minute
    @numbers_in_iteration = {go_fish: nil}
  end

  def next
    raise StopIteration if @numbers_in_iteration.empty?
    number_generator = @numbers_in_iteration.keys.sample

    if number_generator == :go_fish
      add_next_number if @numbers_in_iteration.size < 1_000_000
      self.next
    else
      next_permutation(number_generator)
    end
  end

  private
  def add_next_number
    @numbers_in_iteration[@all_numbers_generator.next] = @k_permutation_seeds.sample.to_enum
  rescue StopIteration # lol, you actually managed to traverse all 2^61 numbers!
    @numbers_in_iteration.delete(:go_fish)
  end

  def next_permutation(number)
    fetch_permutation(number, @numbers_in_iteration[number].next)
  rescue StopIteration # all k permutations for this number were already generated
    @numbers_in_iteration.delete(number)
    self.next
  end

  def fetch_permutation(number_mask, k_permutation)
    k_from_n_indices = number_mask.to_s(2).chars.reverse.map.with_index { |bit, index| index if bit == '1' }.compact
    k_permutation.each_with_object([]) { |order_index, k_from_n_values| k_from_n_values << ALL_CHARACTERS[k_from_n_indices[order_index]] }
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: it turned out that our constraints eliminate too much possibilities. This causes `@all_numbers_generator` to take too much time testing and skipping numbers. I will try to think of a better generator, but everything else remains valid.

---

The old version that generates tokens with uniqueness constraint on the containing characters:

```
numbers          = ('0'..'9').to_a
downcase_letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
upcase_letters   = downcase_letters.map(&:upcase)
all = [numbers, downcase_letters, upcase_letters]
one_of_each_set  = all.map(&:sample)
random_code = (one_of_each_set + (all.flatten - one_of_each_set).sample(7)).shuffle.join
```

Comment: Note that `sample(7)` is sampling without replacement.  For example `7.times.to_a.sample(7) #=> => [0, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3] `.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I didn't completely understand what you mean by "sampling without replacement". Did you mean repetition? Could you explain?

Comment: In statistics you can sample "with" or "without" "replacement". Suppose you have a container with six balls numbered 1 to 6 and you wish to draw a random sample of 3 balls. To sample without replacement, you simply draw out 3 balls at random. They will of course all have different numbers. If you sample with replacement, you draw the first ball, note its number and put it back in the container. Then you draw another ball, note its number, put it back and draw a third. In the latter case you might draw, say, ball 4 twice. btw, it appears that sampling without replacement is what is wanted here.

Comment: I see. I didn't know this was called "sampling with replacement" in English.

Comment: On the last line, you should re-use your `one_of_each_set` variable in place of  `all.map(&:sample)`, otherwise you are not removing the same items from the big list that you add, and may get repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'SafeRandom' Gem [GithubLink](https://github.com/rpatil/safe_random)

It will provide the easiest way to generate random values for Rails 2, Rails 3, Rails 4, Rails 5 compatible.

Here you can use the strong_string method to generate a strong combination of string ( ie combination of the alphabet(uppercase, downcase), number, and symbols

```
# => Strong string: Minumum number should be greater than 5 otherwise by default 8 character string.
require 'safe_random'
puts SafeRandom.strong_string                   # => 4skgSy93zaCUZZCoF9WiJF4z3IDCGk%Y
puts SafeRandom.strong_string(3)                # => P4eUbcK%
puts SafeRandom.strong_string(5)                # => 5$Rkdo
```