# Generate a password string of fixed length with certain required criteria (Capitals, numbers, special characters)

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to generate secure passwords of a certain length that will meet certain criteria.

e.g. I want (say) a 10 letter password that:

Has at least 1 Capital letter

Has at least 1 lower case letter

Has at least 1 number

Has at least 1 underscore (or other character, but underscore is good due to certain restrictions where only underscores are accepted)

I've tried

```
SecureRandom.url_safeBase64(10)
```

but this generates strings that are too long and doesn't guarantee the presence of each restriction.

Wondering if there's an easy way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique random string with alphanumberic required in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848723/unique-random-string-with-alphanumberic-required-in-ruby)

Comment: That's probably fair. My only difference is that my characters don't need to be unique and I'd like to allow some extra special characters. The answers there are pretty good.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to leave it for a couple of days. I think that the answers on that other thread are brilliant, but the thread's hard to find (I didn't find it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
low = ('a'..'d').to_a
up  = ('A'..'Z').to_a
num = ('0'..'9').to_a
u   = ['_']
any = low + up + num + u
pw  = (low.sample(1) + 
       up.sample(1) + 
       num.sample(1) + 
       u.sample(1) +
       any.sample(6)).shuffle.join
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard about built-in out of the box feature, but you might do:

```
samples = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), (0..9), ['_']].map &:to_a
(samples.map(&:sample) + \ # ensure at least one of each group
  (10-4).times.map do      # 4 are already chosen
    samples.flatten[rand(samples.flatten.size)] # pick random
  end).shuffle.join
```